# psycopg2 not escaping quotation from tuple arguments? Using sql.SQL to format arguments

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to dynamically create a table in postgres with psycopg2.  It seems when the arguments are passed, pyscopg2 is not escaping quotations and understanding my query. Code looks like this:

```
input_string_tup = ('col1 int', 'col2 varchar(2)', ...)

create_table_str = sql.SQL("CREATE TABLE {} ({data})").format(
sql.SQL(table_name),
data=sql.SQL(", ").join(sql.Composed(sql.Identifier(i) for i in input_string_tup)
))

execute_batch(cur, create_table_str, [input_string_tup])
```

The error I'm getting:

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at end of input LINE 1: ...", 
"shape_area numeric(8, 6)", "shape_length numeric(8, 6)")
                                                         ^
```

What print(create_table_str.as_string(conn)) outputs:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table ("col1 int", "col2 varchar(2)", "col3 int", ... )
```

**Edit to show modified answer that works with no string concatenation**

```
input_string_tup = (('col1', 'int'), ('col2, varchar(2)'), ...)

create_table_str = sql.SQL("CREATE TABLE {} ({data})").format(
sql.SQL(table_name),
data=sql.SQL(", ").join(sql.Composed([sql.Identifier(i[0]), 
sql.SQL(' '), sql.SQL(i[1])])  for i in input_string_tup))
```

Thanks to Adrian for the help

Comment: After checking the documentation `sql.Identifier` behaves correctly (object names get quoted with double quotes), it's just not developed for data definition.

Comment: It works to insert data though, I used it to insert column names that was a list of strings. Any thoughts on how to get pyscopg2 to recognize the data types inside the quotes?

Comment: Or any other way to dynamically insert column names/types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sql.Identifier is for SQL objects only e.g. table/column names not the types:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Try:

```
input_string_tup = (('col1', 'int'), ('col2', 'varchar(2)')) 

table_name = 'test_table' 

create_table_str = sql.SQL("CREATE TABLE {} ({data})").format( 
sql.SQL(table_name), 
data=sql.SQL(", ").join(sql.Composed(sql.Identifier(i[0]) + sql.SQL(' ' + i[1])  for i in input_string_tup)))   

print(create_table_str.as_string(con))                                                                                                                                    
CREATE TABLE test_table ("col1" int, "col2" varchar(2))

cur.execute(create_table_str)
```

Comment: This worked, I appreciate it. Is this 'safe' from sql injection being it uses string concatenation?

Comment: Well https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html:
class psycopg2.sql.SQL(string) 'The string doesn’t undergo any form of escaping, ...' 
So that means you will need to do some sort of validation on the strings being fed to input_string_tup if they are coming from untrusted sources. To see if others have come up with alternate solutions I would suggest asking this on  the psycopg2 mailing list:
https://www.postgresql.org/list/psycopg/